# how we can get only number skipping fraction in jsf f:convertNumber?

Tags: jsf-2

I have an inputText that takes a value from the user and is bound to a number. If the value is "6000.0", subsequent pages will show it as "6000". Is there any way to format it such that if the user enters a fractional number, it  show like below?

Examples: 
User enters "35545.9" Show "35545" 
user enters "5546.1" Show "5546"
user enter  "7558.767" show 7558
user enter  "548.7943" show 548

Comment: That's some incorrect math there. Are you sure you don't want to round up 35545.9 to 35546?

Comment: i dont want to round up at all...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<h:inputText value="#{receipt.amount}" >
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" />
</h:inputText>
```

or

```
<h:inputText value="#{receipt.amount}" >
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
</h:inputText >
```

to add fraction digits